# Changing module name

Tags: php, mysql

I am customising a opensource phreebooks. I want to change the module names in that. I did change the module names for phreebooks and phreedom successfully, but when i change the name for phreedom i can not print any pdf. I am getting this error

```
User: 1 Company: phree RUN-TIME WARNING: 'Creating default object from empty value' line 50 in file 

F:\wamp\www\phree\modules\report\pages\popup_gen\pre_process.php
```

In line no 50, code is like this

```
 if (isset($_GET['xfld'])) $report->xfilterlist[0]->fieldname = $_GET['xfld'];
```

Can somebody please tell me where exactly i am doing wrong. I have been tying it from past 3 days.

EDITED

`if (isset($_GET['xfld'])) { // check for extra filters
    if (!isset($_GET['xfld'])) $xfld = new stdClass();
    echo "BLANK";
      if (isset($_GET['xfld'])) $report->xfilterlist[0]->fieldname = $_GET['xfld'];
      if (isset($_GET['xcr']))  $report->xfilterlist[0]->default   = $_GET['xcr'];
      if (isset($_GET['xmin'])) $report->xfilterlist[0]->min_val   = $_GET['xmin'];
      if (isset($_GET['xmax'])) $report->xfilterlist[0]->max_val   = $_GET['xmax'];
    }`

i did like this
It displays "BLANK" but actually `isset($_GET['xfld']` is SET from URL.

Comment: $report->xfilterlist[0] might be empty. but I have no way of telling from what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['xfld'] = $xfld;


 $xfld = NULL;
    $xfld->success = false; // Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

PHP will report a different error message if $xfld is already initialized to some value but is not an object:

```
$xfld = something;
$xfld->success = false; // Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

You shoud check whether the object already exists:

```
if (!isset($_GET['xfld'])) $xfld = new stdClass();
```

Otherwise, this code is not an equivalent replacement for the "old PHP" implicit object creation.

Comment: I have posted the code under EDITED section. Actually value is set for `($_GET['xfld'])` through URL like this `http://localhost/phree/index.php?module=report&page=popup_gen&gID=cust:so&date=a&xfld=journal_main.id&xcr=EQUAL&xmin=11`

Comment: Can you try put `echo "BLANK";` under xmax, like: if (isset($_GET['xmax'])) $report->xfilterlist[0]->max_val   = $_GET['xmax'];
echo "BLANK";
    }
Is it displaying blank now?

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['xmax'])) { $report->xfilterlist[0]->max_val = $_GET['xmax']; echo "BLANK"; }
    }` - not getting "BLANK"

Comment: So after it try to move echo "blank" up before every $_get, I think problem is in some name of $_get..

Comment: as `$_GET['xmax'] ` is not set in URL, so only for this i am not getting echo message, rest all i am getting the echo

Comment: Did you try to put it in url? 
Maybe problem is not here

Comment: sorry, i did not get u